# How to disable a keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard

Im looking how I can disable my laptop keyboard, I looked into the Device manager and there is no "Disable this device", Don't want to uninstall it, just turn it off.

I'm just troubleshooting some hardware issues.

any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: How were you planning to unlock it again if the keyboard isn't working?  Or do you mean you want to use an external keyboard instead?

Comment: @Col - I'm thinking he would use the mouse.

Comment: @idigas some kind of super secret mouse gesture presumably?

Comment: Autohotkey could do it, and have a suitably obscure reactivation hotkey. (Like, say, doublepress q while holding winkey with caps lock on and the cd drive open)

Comment: i prefer using a hammer.  think i still have a few keys from the last keyboard i disabled.  yep, here they are, `K`, `I`, `U`, `C`, `T`, `F`.

Comment: @Col - Some sort of "enable keyboard" checkbox ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) from Microsoft

> The DevCon utility is a command-line
>   utility that acts as an alternative to
>   Device Manager. Using DevCon, you can
>   enable, disable, restart, update,
>   remove, and query individual devices
>   or groups of devices. DevCon also
>   provides information that is relevant
>   to the driver developer and is not
>   available in Device Manager.

the link contain a detailed page about how to use it,

for your case, just put

> devcon find *

To lists device instances of all devices that are present on the local computer.then,

> devcon disable [ your-keyboard-HardwareID ]

to disable devices that match that specific hardware or instance ID

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work with Windows 7

Comment: @Shivan Raptor  In Windows Driver Kit for windows 7, there is a version which works, if I remember corectly.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: The Windows Driver Kit is 620mb

Comment: Did someone success to disable keyabord like this? I am able to disable my mouse but it doesnt work on keyboard. It says ": Disable failed".

Comment: Downloaded and installed Windows Driver Kit (WDK), but could not get this to work on Windows 7.  Never found devcon.exe.

Comment: You can quickly find your keyboard(s) with the command `devcon find *keyboard*`

Answer (score 14):

Revolter answer is actually not correct.

When trying the described manipulation, I got the following message:

```
ACPI\PNP0303\4&378F8A46&0                                   : Disable failed
No devices disabled
```

I think that the reality is too bad: there is no **nice** solution for disabling a laptop keyboard without physically removing it (if you uninstall the driver, Windows will re-install it automatically).

See this discussion forum for more precision: https://www.techsupportforum.com/hardware-support/laptop-support/250095-how-disable-laptop-keyboard.html

However, there is a way to uninstall a laptop keyboard with software: by installing an incompatible driver!!

The instructions are:

1. Go to Device Manager and select the keyboard driver for your laptop. Right-click -> Properties.
2. Click on the driver panel and select the "Update..." button.
3. Here, you can choose an incompatible driver (you should unselect the option "Find compatible driver"). The one I have chosen (and the safer) is the "HID Keyboard Device".
4. Restart and that's it!! You are done.

I hope it will help other folks here.

Comment: Posting to confirm that installing an incompatible driver as advised by fabien4747 of course works. When guessing for an incompatible driver, I chose a different language – Japanese – when my keyboard is US. I also chose a different brand of driver software – Toshiba – when my laptop is a Dell. The system needs to be rebooted after the hopefully incompatible driver is installed. Thanks fabien4747! This advice saved a Vista laptop which had faulty keys which were registering when not pressed and interfering with an external USB keyboard.

Comment: This worked!  First I downloaded Windows Driver Kit (WDK), installed on Windows 7,  and couldn't find "DevCon.exe".  This is a much quicker solution to disable the keyboard.  In devices, look to see how your keyboard is connected (USB or keyboard port).  Select a driver of the OTHER type and it won't be compatible.

Answer (score 4):

The only way is to physically disconnect the keyboard.

See this article : ["Repairing the keyboards of Compaq laptops"](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~motl/hp-keyboard/compaq-presario.html).

If what the guy describes in the above page solves the problem, you might save yourself the trouble.

If it doesn't, then repeat the operation, but just omit the described step 8 and do not reconnect the cable.

(I take no responsibility for any mistakes in the execution of this operation.)

Comment: any easy way ? :)

Comment: Yes, take it to a repairman.

Comment: Another idea is to install on purpose an incompatible driver for the keyboard. This will disable it for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Few suggestions:
[LockKeyboard](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/LockKeyboard.aspx)
[KeyboardLock](http://www.rixler.com/keyboard_lock.htm)

or maybe the best yet: [Kid-key-lock](http://www.100dof.com/kidkeylock.html) (don't ask, I didn't make the name)

Why do you wish to lock your keyboard ? Wouldn't just locking the user out do the job ?

Comment: Thanks Idigas, Im using a second keyboard and I just want to lock the laptop-keyboard (the embedded one), these tools are locking all the keyboards.

Comment: Oh, I see. Ups, yeah. I understood it wrong then - I thought you wanted to lock your keyboard for, when, for example, you're working and putting stuff on your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out!
http://www.100dof.com/products/kid-key-lock

I had the same problem. It seems to work pretty well.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Explain the product a little bit more, make the answer more independent of the link. Welcome to Super User!

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the answer provided by fabien7474! With one slight difference - my Asus UL56V with Windows 7 showed "Keyboard Device Filter" and "HID Keyboard Device". By disabling the second option, I ended up disabling the USB keyboard :) But disabling Keyboard Device Filter by changing to a Japanese keyboard did the trick for me!

P.S. No one on the whole Internet managed to come up with such an elegant fix for such a common (and serious) problem!

Cheers!