# Dusting Laptop keyboard

Tags: keyboard, cleaning

Is there a way to temporarily disable a laptop's keyboard in order to clean/dust it off, other than having to turn off the computer?

Comment: c.f. [How to disable a keyboard?](http://superuser.com/questions/44572/how-to-disable-a-keyboard)

Comment: How about unplugging it?

Comment: To clean very dirty keyboards, Leo Laporte recommends putting them through the dishwasher and letting them dry for a few days (yes, seriously).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, you could lock the screen <kbd>win</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> on windows or do something similar. You could probably also disable it from device manager.

I'm sure there's something similar on linux, but that is heavily desktop environment dependent.

Comment: mostly ctrl+alt+L

Answer (score 10):

You can get a can of compressed air which will clean the keyboard without actualy pressing the keys.

Answer (score 7):

Open up a text editor and let that take the hit - or use a natural bristle brush (no static build up) with long hairs so that there's little pressure on the keys/gaps.

Comment: Tended to do the former, but every so often you hit a... unfortunate key combination

Answer (score 3):

You can also just sleep you computer instead of turning it off.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [KeyboardLocker](http://www.howtogeek.com/geekers/up/Keyboard%20Locker.zip) to lock your keyboard , some key  combinations  will still work but its unlikely that you would press them , while cleaning.
Here is a [how-to](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11570/disable-the-keyboard-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows/) for the tool.

Comment: I am still having trouble understanding why would you really need to do it  ? I mean why not just switch the device off or remove the keyboard ? or do you frequently drop bowls of ramen on you keyboard after a 1000 line code sprint which you have not been able to save ?