# My laptop keyboard is going nuts. Still not working after replacing it. It also affects an external wireless keyboard and on screen one

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop

Most keys of my laptop (Lenovo W541) keyboard started not to function. Only 3 keys worked ("i", "tab", and a third one I forgot). It could have been after I spilled some water on the keyboard from my glass. It makes sense. However, at restart, the wireless keyboard and on-screen keyboard would not work as well (only the same 3 keys work on them!). The on-screen keyboard would show that ctrl is pressed (see image below). That would be for a few minutes  (<10) only, after that ctrl becomes unpressed on the on-screen keyboard, both my wireless and on-screen keyboard start to work, and the laptop keyboard still does not work except for those 3 keys. So I can finally enter my password and work with my external keyboard. I cannot reboot or put the laptop on sleep, since everytime the screen with the password shows up I am back to the beginning, with only 3 keys working on all 3 keyboards (laptop, on screen and wireless). I bought a new laptop keyboard and installed it. Same exact problem at restart, only the same 3 keys are working and ctrl is pressed on on-screen keyboard. The only difference: once ctrl becomes unpressed, now 80% of the new laptop keyboard works rather than only 3 (all letters work, some special keys like ctrl, alt, arrows, etc don't work). Any idea of how to fix this? Is there a physical damage or a software issue? I tried:

1. Reboot in safe mode and disable all services. Same behaviour
2. Since you cannot un-install a laptop keyboard, I installed an uncompatible At&t driver ([as for here](https://superuser.com/a/72684/192653)). Maybe I picked a partially compatible driver, funny think is that it didn't change anything (laptop keyboard still behaving the same way, with only 3 keys working and ctrl pressed at startup)

[image]

Comment: Did the spilled water get inside the laptop?  Probably. Now it needs to be serviced.

Comment: but this behaviour is kinda ackward. As long as I don't reboot or make it asleep, everything works with an external keyboard. Why at reboot/sleep it gets messed up?

Comment: And not sure if it went. Once I replaced the keyboard I did not notice water or stains

Comment: Does this mean you've fixed the issue? "Once I replaced the keyboard I did not notice water or stains." Also, water could have damaged the *keyboard controller*.

Comment: No issue is still there. I wrote "Same exact problem at restart, only the same 3 keys are working and ctrl is pressed on on-screen keyboard. The only difference: once ctrl becomes unpressed, now 80% of the new laptop keyboard works rather than only 3 (all letters work, some special keys like ctrl, alt, arrows, etc don't work)"